# How to add MySQL to my nginx, which is running on windows 7?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, nginx

I used [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9Pf4RigRvI) to set up PHP on my server, but now my question is about MySQL. There are a lot of tutorials for unix like systems but for windows I can't find one which would work for me.

I took a look [at this one](http://eksith.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/nginx-php-mysql-windows/), but it seems to be out of date, cause I can't find some files (*my-medium.ini, my.ini*) in mysql-5.6.15 folder.

Comment: I don't see how nginx and MySQL are related? Once you install MySQL on your computer, you need to access it with PHP (or another server side language). I'm just saying that you whould be able to take the "mysql and php part" of any tutorial, even if it's about installing Apache, MySQL and PHP.

Comment: So there is no need to somehow connect it with web server?

Comment: If you mean that you want to display data from a php site contained in a MySQL database, yes, you can do that. That you're using NGinx or Apache, it doesn't matter.  Your request will look like this : Your browser -> Nignx -> php execution (reading code etc) -> connexion to your MySQL database.  So you could read a tutorial on "how to install a MySQL database on windows 7" and another one on "How to query a MySQL database with php".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try an answer, easier to format ;)

You need to realize that there is no link between Nginx and MySQL. Nginx doesn't need to know that MySQL exists and the opposite is true.

And there is a small link with Php and MySQL, but in fact, it doesn't matter if the database is on your computer or another server. Php will just take the URL of the database to connect to it. If it's on your computer or somewhere else, it will work. You could even connect to multiple different databases on different computers.

All this to say that all you need to do (related to the MySQL installation) is to install MySQL on your Windows 7 machine. If the installation worked (normally, only executing an EXE file and pressing next, next, next), you'll be able to connect to it with php. Just note the PORT where MySQL will listen (it should be displayed in the wizard installation) and also remember the username password that you'll set for connecting to your MySQL server (it should be asked throughout the installation wizard).

Comment: Thanks! Since i haven`t been in common with mysql yet, i thought it has something to do with webserver, cause Apache install sets everything up.